# How to calculate arcus sinus in solidity?

Tags: solidity

I have a function to calculate sinus from [this library](https://github.com/Sikorkaio/sikorka/blob/master/contracts/trigonometry.sol). How can I calculate arcus sinus and arcus cosine?

Comment: by arcus sinus do you mean arcos(sin())?

Comment: I think it's just `arcsin()`.

Comment: @haxerl `arcsin()` and also how to calculate  `arcos()`

Answer (score 2):

The library you are referring to approximates sin and cos via [piecewise linear function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Piecewise_linear_function).  This approach is applicable to arcsin and arccos functions as well, you just need different table of points.

Also, as long as you already have sin function, you may find `y = arcsin(x)` by solving `sin y = x` equation using [bisection method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bisection_method), or some other method for finding equation roots.